# Disable dragging of metaboxes in custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I am able to disable dragging of metaboxes sitewide with this function:

```
function disable_drag_metabox() {
wp_deregister_script('postbox');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_drag_metabox' );
```

But I want it only on a custom post type.
I tried the usual:

```
function disable_drag_metabox() {
global $current_screen;
if( 'event' == $current_screen->post_type ) wp_deregister_script('postbox');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_drag_metabox' );
```

and also this one:

```
function disable_drag_metabox() {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if( in_array( $screen->id, array( 'event' ) ) ) {
    wp_deregister_script('postbox');
}
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_drag_metabox' );
```

Sadly it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? the custom post type is called event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current screen isn't setup on the `admin_init` hook. That's why `global $current_screen` and `get_current_screen()` don't work.

Every admin page has a `load-something` hook that fires after the current screen is set up. Since you say this is for an events custom post type, you should use the `load-post.php` hook. So you're code would look like:

```
function disable_drag_metabox() {
  if( 'events' === get_current_screen()->post_type ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'postbox' );
  }
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'disable_drag_metabox' );
```

You can use the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to figure out what hooks fire on each page and in what order. It also does a lot of other cook stuff.